# IP Matching with long2ip gives different results

Tags: php, apache

here it is code

```
echo (0xffffffff << (32 - 26));
```

it gives -64 on local host where php version latest 5.4.3

on live hosting it gives, 274877906880 where php version is 5.3.27

does there any solution to take same results

original line of code is

```
$mask = long2ip($x) == $ip_arr[1] ? $x : (0xffffffff << (32 - $ip_arr[1]));
```

Comment: I know that there's a difference in the way that 32/64 bit machines response. Can it be that the local and the server are different? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php#105263)

Comment: This looks very much like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).